# Android: When I set an OnClickListener for a ListView

Tags: java, android, user-interface

```
    lv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){

        }
    });
```

Does `v` refer to the ListView `lv` or the specific item selected in the list?

Comment: Removed salutation: "Thanks in advance.", don't do it next time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that `v` refers to the whole `ListView`.  To add a click handler for an item, you want to use [AdapterView.setOnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html).

Answer (score 5):

There is a setOnItemClickListener for what you want.

Answer (score 3):

`onClickListener` just listens to a click on the entire View.  `v` will be the `ListView`.

What you probably want is `onItemClickListener` instead of `onClickListener`.

Or you may want to extend `ListActivity` and override `onListItemClick()`

Answer (score 3):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,long itemID) {

        View itemView = view;
        String fromDate = ((TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.fromDate)).getText().toString();
        int position = (int) arg0.getSelectedItemId();
        Log.d(TAG, "ListView Selected : "+fromDate+" Position:"+position+" arg2:"+arg2+" arg3:"+itemID);
    }
});
```