# How to put onclickListener on List view

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

How do I set onclickListener on Listview wordList to retrive the text displayed in the list? Also where should I write that function? I am a naive Android developer and could not find appropriate examples of it!

```
@Override  
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)  
{  
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)  
    {  
        // Populate the wordsList with the String values the recognition engine thought it heard  
        matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);            
        wordsList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,matches));  
    }  
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
}
```

Comment: check it : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240411/android-when-i-set-an-onclicklistener-for-a-listview

Answer (score 2):

in your `onActivityCreated` use

```
ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setOnClcikListener();
```

if its a `ListActivity,ListFragment` other wise `getListView()` wont work and you have to `findViewById` and do the same

Answer (score 2):

For on item click, use this:

```
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    // Set adapter here
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        }
    });
```

and if you want to add a context menu:

```
    listView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new OnCreateContextMenuListener() {
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            menu.add(0, 1, 0, "View");
            menu.add(0, 2, 0, "Edit");
            menu.add(0, 3, 0, "Delete");
        }
    });

public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo menuInfo;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case 1:
        //  Do something
        break;
    case 2:
        //  Do something        
        break;
    case 3:
        //  Do something
    default:
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
    return true;
}
```